# Export LUT from nodes

Tags: compositing-nodes, lut

Blender's compositor can be really cool to change colors, but it's really to slow to render a full movie. I was thinking to do some color management in Blender (notably using the HueCorrect node that is not available in KDEnlive), export it as a 3D LUT, and then apply the LUT directly in KDEnlive.

However, I can't find how to export some nodes into a LUT, is it possible? I understand that nodes can do much more things than LUT, but if we assume that the nodes only do local changes (i.e. turn one color into another color without considering any neighbouring cells), then it makes sense to create a LUT out of it I guess.

Thanks!

Comment: Well 3.5 version compositor is now fast enough (i think it's because it's using GPU processing). So you don't need to export 3d lut from nodes. I'd like to do the opposite, import 3d LUTs to the compositor.

Comment: @Jefferson Only viewport compositing uses GPU acceleration now(3.5), the Compositor does not. So it's not fast yet. I wonder why you think speed would have anything to do with the need for this functionality...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

afaik, there is no solution within Blender. I hope it comes soon. But there is a workaround.

**The workaround**:

You create a LUT with gimp and the gmix addon from a before image and an after image.

Steps:

1. **select your reference image** which is used as source:
   1.1 The choices:
   You have 2 choices: you choose as source a) a 64x64 LUT or b) your image
   1.2 the effect of choices:
   a ) your changes will be applied to all colors
   b ) your changes will be applied only to the colors which are contained by your
   1.3 how you get the picture
   a ) you download a LUT example picture:
   therefore you google: 64x64 LUT
   or you can find one here https://gist.github.com/Yanrishatum/86794e9e663a7e343f9ef66e8b0f38ae
   b ) you have your own picture. just use it.
2. **edit image**: edit the selected source image with blender and safe it.
   Therefore you load in compositor with the image noda and link all your nodes and safe it at the end as a new image.
3. **create a LUT with Gimp and the addon gmic**.

3.1 download and install gimp: https://www.gimp.org/ - only if you dont have it

3.2 download and install gmic: https://gmic.eu/ - only if you dont have it

3.3 creat a LUT with gmic filter in gimp:

3.3.1 start gimp

3.3.2 insert before and after image in 2 layer

- insert before image
- add new layer: shift+ctrl+n or gimp menu->layer->new layer click. now just click ok
- insert new image in the 2nd newly created layer

3.3.3 create lut:

Gimp Menu -> Filter -> G'MIC-Qt.. <- click.
Now the gmic window opens.

GMIC menu on left side -> colors -> CLUT from After - Before Layer <- click.
Now you configure the LUT creation:

Chose as you like. I select:

- "Safe CLUT as .Cube or .png File"
- 64
- myfolder
- myoutputname
- influence of colorsamples 100%
- layers: active and below. <-- may be different.

I hope my answer helps you. Good luck.